# How to check various "is" conditions and typecast accordingly?

Tags: c#

I have three classes called School, Teacher and Student. Now let us say I have a method called GetAcademicDetailsOfCity() which will yield and object of any of types in School, Teacher and Student or may be a class derived by any of three.

At run time i want to check below :

```
var instance = GetAcademicDetailsOfCity();
if (instance is School)
{
     //What i actually want is something like  
      var result = new School();   
      result.property1 = (School)instance.property1  
      result.property2 = (School)instance.property2  
      result.property3 = (School)instance.property3  
}

if (instance is Teacher)
{
      var result = new Teacher();  
      result.property1 = (Teacher)instance.property1  
      result.property2 = (Teacher)instance.property2  
      result.property3 = (Teacher)instance.property3  
}

if (instance is Student)
{
      var result = new Student();
      result.property1 = (Student)instance.property1  
      result.property2 = (Student)instance.property2  
      result.property3 = (Student)instance.property3 
}
```

How do i check the above conditions in one go

```
if (instance is School || instance is Teacher || instance is Student)
{
      //What should be the casting of instance below ??
      var result = (????)instance;
}
return result;
```

With this result instance I will create a report of Students in a particular school city wise. Please let me know in case more details are required. I will be happy to give details as much as I can :).

Comment: You should show the rest of the code.

Comment: You need to show the rest of your code, because right now there is no point of the cast as you don't do anything with `result`, what you are doing with `result` affects how you solve the problem.

Comment: Looks like you should re-think your design. What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps this is the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I believe you should not mix different types of objects. If you want schools of the city - get schools. You need teachers - get teachers. Why you need this 'russian roulette'?

Comment: what i do with result ?? I could not give more details as I am not allowed to divulge details of exact scenario. But I will try my best. Please bear with me folks. I will edit the details and post

Answer (score 1):

If `GetAcademicDetailsOfCity()` returns a common base type (i.e. not just `Object`), let's call it `MyBaseType`, you can use `else if` like this to improve the efficiency (because it only executes one `if` block instead of all three like you have it in your question):

```
if (instance is School)
{
    var result = (School) instance;
    // Do stuff specific to an instance of School
}
else if (instance is Teacher)
{
    var result = (Teacher) instance;
    // Do stuff specific to an instance of Teacher
}
else if (instance is Student)
{
    var result = (Student) instance;
    // Do stuff specific to an instance of Student
}
```

Comment: If the return of `GetAcademicDetailsOfCity` is `MyBaseType`, then either it *is* a `School` and you don't need to cast, or it isn't. The only reason to cast would be to use specific `School` functionality (but then you can't store it in a variable of `MyBaseType`).

Comment: What's the point of storing the casted object back into `result` of `MyBaseType`? Did you just miss the `var`?

Comment: @31eee384 -- You're right, I'm not actually trying to use this code so I wasn't thinking of it that way.  See update.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would want each of those 3 classes to implement a common interface or inherit from a base class that provides a `GetAcademicDetailsOf` function.  That way you only have minimal casting to worry about.

```
AcademicDetails results = instance.GetAcademicDetails();
```

Comment: Common interface will work if all three types are processed in exactly same way. Currently we know nothing about usage of `instance`